# When is two-step regression sensible?

Tags: regression

I'm sorry if this is trivial or a known problem.

Assume $x$ is a Gaussian random variable in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $z = A^T x + e$ for some $A \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times d}$ and independent $d$-dimensional Gaussian noise $e$. Assume further that $y=b^T z + \epsilon$ for some $b \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and again, Gaussian noise $\epsilon$. Thus, $y = (Ab)^T x + \epsilon'$ for noise $\epsilon'$ that is composed of $\epsilon$ and $b^T e$.

Question: Assuming I only observe $x$ on test data, should I predict $z$ first and then predict $y$, or directly predict $y$? Does this problem have a name?

Comment: Which of $A$ and $b$ are known and which need to be estimated?  If both are unknown, your model doesn't look identifiable.

Comment: @whuber Both are unknown. I don't know about identifiability, but could we not still compare generalisation error between direct estimation of $(x,y)$ and the two-step approach (first predicting $z$ and then $y$)?

Comment: If you don't observe $z,$ then the two-step approach cannot possibly improve on the direct approach.  Indeed, how would you even get started?

Comment: @whuber Formally, training data would contain triplets $(x,y,z)$. However, on test data, observing $z$ could be impossible (e.g. because it is very costly). But thanks for the answer, I am busy now but will think about why this holds for myself later

Comment: Different A and b may provide a same solution to your problem. This makes them nuisance parameters. Do you know something more about them (like assumptions about their distribution) ? Otherwise there is no way to solve this problem. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm